# Injection of service in service giving error (Circular dependency injection)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, frontend, angular-services

I have started building an application on Angular 5 butI am facing an error issue when injecting a service in another service.

Below is my dataService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication/authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private headers;
  public user: any;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private auth: AuthenticationService
  ) {
if (auth.loggedIn) {
      this.setHeader();
    }
  }
}
```

AuthenticationService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { error } from 'selenium-webdriver';

import { DataService } from '../../services/dataservice/data.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  public loggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private dataservice: DataService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
}
```

Here I am injecting another custom service, i.e., AuthenticationService.

However, while running it gives me an error and I am not able to figure out why its throwing error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DataService: ([object Object], ?).
```

Have injected in the provider in my app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
    DataService,
    AuthenticationService,
    AuthGuard
  ],
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post authenticationservice

Comment: have now posted the auth service as well.....

Comment: You need to solve circular dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your code You have a circular dependency between DataService and AuthenticationService which is not possible with constructor injection

To fix this, you can do

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  public token: any;
  dataService: DataService;
  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    injector:Injector;
    private router: Router
  ) {
    setTimeout(() => this.dataService= injector.get(DataService));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will I have to do it in both the service or just any one of them?

Comment: You need in both